# How to fit a Dirichlet mixed effect model in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, biostatistics, compositional-data, dirichlet-regression

I have a compositional data from an arena experiment in which the duration of an animal in specific zones was denoted. The time in the arena was fixed for all individuals which makes the durations compositional. My two fixed factors are a numerical social factor and the categorical group size with 2 levels. Additionally, I had several replicate groups for each group size, which I would like to include as random grouping variable. It looks something like this, Pen is the group, the max. duration (offset) would be 600:

```
> head(fullData[c(1,2,16, 35, 77), c("Pen", "ID","Elo", "Group_Size","Familiar", "Stranger", "Between")])
   Pen ID        Elo Group_Size Familiar Stranger  Between
1:   A CC  0.5732262      Large      224      173      203
2:   A FE -0.1819106      Large      168      174      258
3:   B DZ -0.5245459      Large      137      200      263
4:   C MT -0.4489969      Large      137       47      416
5:   F LM  1.7574755      Small       97       28      475
```

Because of the nature of my data (cumulative, dependent) I don't see any other option than running a Dirichlet Regression, however the `DirichLetReg` package does not include any option for mixed effects, as far as I know. The formula I am aiming for is:

```
(Familiar, Stranger, Between) ~ Elo*Group_Size + (1|Pen)
```

Also, in this paper: https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.13234 they state that there is no package implemented to their knowledge, but that was 2019, so I am hoping there might be an option by now?

I would really like to try and avoid the Log-Ratio Transformation, as it is such a pain to interpret the outcome. Looking forward to the suggestions.

Comment: If you are comfortable switching to bayesian, brms has support for the dirichlet distribution. Here is an example: https://numerilab.io/en/analysis_projects/DirichletElections (No random effects in the example but in brms you would specify random effects the same way as your formula above)

Comment: Thanks @AngelosAmyntas looks promising.